# ¿Como hago para quitar un none en Python?

Tags: python, lista

soy principiante y estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Python que pide el largo de la lista y me pide una cantidad de palabras acorde a la lista, todo va bien con mi código hasta que al ejecutarlo, en el momento de pedir la palabra, me sale un "none", puedo escribir y crear la lista pero me sale el none cada vez que me pide la palabra.

````
palabra=""
lista=[]
if numero<1:
    print("La lista debe ser mayor a 0")
else:
    for palabra in range(numero):
        palabra=input(print(f"ingrese la palabra: "))
        lista.append(palabra)
print(lista) ```
````

Comment: quita el print de dentro del input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
palabra=input(print(f"ingrese la palabra: "))
```

Primero se ejecuta el `print()`, que devuelve `None`. Luego se ejecuta el `input()`. Este recibe como parámetro algo a imprimir, de lo cual se obtiene el `None` en pantalla.

La forma correcta es:

```
palabra=input(f"ingrese la palabra: ")
```